# Why did this accessibility not cause a problem until it was deployed on another PC?

Tags: c#, private, public

I have a project that when I gave the built .exe to another user, it failed. After some investigation, the reason it was failing was because one of the classes had unspecified accessibility. I.e. `class Db`. After changing this to `public class Db`, the problem was solved.

The file structure is as follows:

- Solution File.sln

  - Form1.cs
  - Controller.cs
  - Model.cs
  - Db.cs

The only reason I discovered the possibility this was an issue was due to the JIT debugger, when the exe crashed on the other machine:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for "Db" threw an exception at Db..cctor()

I ran the same exe on my machine with no issue, and even when I stepped through it using the VS debugger, it didn't have any issues with the (lack of) access to the class.

Why did this run on my machine, but not on another's?

Comment: Maybe code was hit that you didn't actually test. It's hard to say for sure while not being able to see any of the code in question. There's nothing inherent with the class not being public that would make the code fail. It would only be a problem if you tried to do something like assign an internal class to a public field.

Comment: @John I can add the specific lines that I believe may have caused the problem?

Comment: It sounds like a COM+ dependency is not installed on that machine. The managed code is there, but a non-managed dependency is not installed.